# node.js mqtt client using TLS

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosca

I am trying to implement a node.js mqtt client with TLS using the package below;

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#client

The code for running mqtt client without TLS is as follows;

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('presence')
  client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer 
  console.log(message.toString())
  client.end()
})
```

How should the above code be modified to use TLS on the mqtt client?

The mosca MQTT broker was run as a stand-alone using the command below;

```
mosca --key ./tls-key.pem --cert ./tls-cert.pem --http-port 3000 --http-bundle --http-static ./ | pino
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should be enough to change the `protocol` part of the URL to `mqtts://`

`mqtts://test.mosquitto.org`.

**Self-signed certificates**

You can pass the following option to the `connect` function when using self-signed certificates (for testing purposes only):

```
mqtt.connect('mqtts://test.mosquitto.org', {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```

Comment: This won't work because the broker is is using a self signed certificate so the client won't know to trust it.

Comment: @user91579631 When using self-signed certificates, you can pass `rejectUnauthorized: false` as option. Edit: I added the information to the answer.

Comment: Seems there is no need for the client to know the cert and key used by the broker. Thanks.

Comment: @user91579631 the client should know the certificate of what ever signed the brokers certificate (the same things when self signed) or there is no way to know if somebody else it impersonating it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to provide the `mqtt.connect()` function with an options object which includes the CA certificate to use to verify the connection.

The options object needs to include a `ca` key that points to the certificate used to sign the brokers certificate. As it looks like your using a self signed certificate this will be the same one used by the broker.

The `ca` key is described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback)

Or you can allow any certificate with the `rejectUnauthorized` key as mentioned in @notion's answer. But that makes it impossible to detect if somebody is impersonating your broker

Comment: How can I specify `ca` key in the option? I couldn't find a `ca` option [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt#client)

Comment: But it does say that the options object is also passed to `tls.connect()` so it can contain any of those options as well.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.